# Dual Monitor Display Not Working

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I just purchased two new monitors (Samsung 21.5" S22C300H model) and wanted to hook them up to my PC I built. I have an HDMI port on my video card (Nvidia GTX 660) and an HDMI port and a DVI port on my motherboard (ASUS P8Z77-V LK), and I'm using an Intel Core i5-3570K processor.

For some reason, the second monitor never gets detected. I have the first monitor using the HDMI port on the video card and the second I've tried using both DVI or HDMI and I can't seem to get either to function.

What should I be looking for?

Comment: Your onboard (motherboard) graphics adapter is probably disabled. Do you not have more than one port on the graphics card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to use a combination of both Onboard graphics and your expansion card, Check your Device manager and verify both `Display Adapters` are present. If they are not, check your BIOS for a setting to enable both onboard and pci-e display adapters. Not all hardware configurations have this capability, or are compatible.

The normal solution to this is that if you closely inspect your video card you will find multiple connections, VGA, DVI, HDMI, HDMI mini, etc... The combination of these ports may not always meet your needs but most video cards come with adapters to allow them to be usable to you.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem is. I'll have to try to figure out the onboard video card. I bought it from Newegg and the description from there says:
Onboard Video Chipset
Supported only by CPU with integrated graphic

Comment: Integrated HD Graphics, Most likley Intel. I'm researching your EUFI BIOS Now. Should be able to find that setting for you shortly

Comment: In your BIOS - (Top Right) Exit/Advanced -> Advanced -> North Bridge Setup -> ??? I couldn't find anything about what's in that menu but I'm sure it's there

Comment: Thanks a lot @Oxymoron, what I ended up doing is I realized I had a DVI-VGA adapter that came with my video card and I was able to use that to hook both monitors up to my video card. Now they are both working!